# compare checked products and display them in next page

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I have a scenario that In a page I have list of products where user can check any of the products to compare. then I have to collect the data of the checked products and comapre them in next page. I have to do this in jquery

Can anyone give me suggestion on how to approach these kind of situations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 Output list of your products with checkboxes. They will go to request after form submit.
2 On next page do your compare.